# Run WinPhone7 Emulator on Windows7 under VirtualBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation, virtualbox

My main OS is Windows XP. I install VirtualBox and now have Windows 7 under VirtualBox. I install WinPhone7 Emulator and try run it. But all that I can see is window of emulator with text "Windows Emulator is doing a complete OS boot...". I waited a very long time. I tried to reboot, reinstall the Windows7 and many more. Result of my attempts is zero. It is possible run WinPhone7 Emulator under Virtual Box? What I can do for work with WinPhone7 Emulator without switch main OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator doesn't support running under a VM.

[Setup and System Requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

The emulator is a VM itself which is partly what makes this unsupported.

Some people have had varying results running under unsupported environments such as XP, VMWare, Bootcamp... but as yet I've not seen anything posted for the VM you mention.

Comment: Can you point me to any article which states that the WP7 emulator runs on any other virtualization solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have a step by step procedure here: [Windows Phone 8 SDK on a Virtual Machine with Working Emulator](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator)

It uses VMWare but it does allows you to run the Windows Phone 8 emulator in a VM.

I've been using this for a few days with good results. I dont have a Windows Phone 8 device yet, so I didn't tried to deploy but its good enough to start playing with it.